# EmberJS 1.0.0 RC7 run code after images load

Tags: image, view, ember.js, controller, resize

I'm trying to resize images after the view and images load on screen.
I have this TAG route and after update the EmberJS to RC7 I saw that the didInsertedElement stopped to work like before, it run one time only, but I need it to run every time I enter the view.

So I tried to run the code on setupController like this:

```
App.TagRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params) {
    return App.TKRPTumblr.findAll(params.tag);
},
setupController: function(controller, tag) {
    if(typeof tag === 'object'){
        controller.set('content', tag.response);
    }else{
        App.TKRPTumblr.findAll(tag)
        .then(function(data) {
            controller.set('content', data.response);       
        });
    }
    this.resizeView();
},
resizeView: function(){
    var WIDTH = 0, RATIO, IMG, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, FINAL_WIDTH, SIDEBAR_WIDTH = $('#sidebar').outerWidth(), MAX_WIDTH = $(window).width() - SIDEBAR_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT = $(window).height() - 125;

    if($('html .post').find('img').length > 0){
        $('.post').each(function(){
            IMG = $(this).find('img');
            IMG_WIDTH = IMG.attr('width');
            IMG_HEIGHT = IMG.attr('height');
            if(IMG_WIDTH > MAX_WIDTH){
                RATIO = MAX_WIDTH / WIDTH;
                IMG.width(MAX_WIDTH).height(IMG_HEIGHT * RATIO);

            }
            if(IMG_HEIGHT > MAX_HEIGHT){
                RATIO = MAX_HEIGHT / IMG_HEIGHT;
                IMG.width(IMG_WIDTH * RATIO).height(MAX_HEIGHT);
            }
            WIDTH += IMG.width();
        });
            if(isNaN(WIDTH)){
                WIDTH = $('.post img').width() + SIDEBAR_WIDTH;
                $('body').children('.ember-view').innerWidth(WIDTH);
            }else{
                WIDTH += SIDEBAR_WIDTH + 100;
                $('body').children('.ember-view').innerWidth(WIDTH);
            }
            var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
            evt.initEvent('_htmlReady', true, true);
            document.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }else{
        Ember.run.next(this, function() {
            this.resizeView();
        });
    }
}

});
```

Unfortunately it didn't worked as well :/ I can't figure out now how to do that :(( can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it run one time only, but I need it to run every time I enter the view.

If you rely on data returned by your `model` hook, then I guess you should rather use the routes `afterModel` hook, this is called every time you enter the route and the `model` is resolved.

```
App.TagRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function() {
    this.resizeView();
  }
  ...
});
```

But if you only care to invoke your function *every* time the route is entered no matter if the model is resolved or not, then using the routes `activate` hook is also an option:

```
App.TagRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.resizeView();
  }
  ...
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you :) worked haha, just need to find out why the images isn't resizing haha

Comment: there's a way to update the bindAttr after I calculate the final width and height? because, when I refresh the page the images seems to resize, but when I click the link to load the images, it load in full size :/ and don't resize, and I'm using bindAttr for the width and height ;o

Comment: @PedroCostaNeves, you could bind it to a Computed property or use an observer?

Comment: hmmm dont know how, never heard about that :/ btw, many thanks for the help :)